# Need help displaying Itembox values

Tags: vb.net

Im brand new to visual basic and im having a hard time displaying the itembox values to my label display. Any Ideas?

[image: http://i49.tinypic.com/n368ut.png]

```
Private Sub frmMain_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load
    'fill the list box with values
    lstNames.Items.Add("Smith, Joe")
    lstNames.Items.Add("Jones, Mary")
    lstNames.Items.Add("Adkari, Joel")
    lstNames.Items.Add("Lin, Sue")
    lstNames.Items.Add("Li, Vicky")
    lstNames.SelectedIndex = 0
End Sub

Private Sub MainForm_MouseClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.Windows.Forms.MouseEventArgs) Handles Me.MouseClick
    Select Case (lstNames.SelectedIndex)
        Case 0
            lblDisplay.Text = "3388"
        Case 1
            lblDisplay.Text = "3356"
        Case 2
            lblDisplay.Text = "2487"
        Case 3
            lblDisplay.Text = "1111"
        Case 4
            lblDisplay.Text = "2222"
    End Select
End Sub
```

Comment: Did you mean to handle the Form.MouseClick event, or perhaps a Button.Click event? As you have it now, this code works for me (changes the label text) when I click anywhere on the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd try moving your code from the MainForm.MouseClick event to lstNames.ItemSelected

Double clicking on the lstNames control in the design view should create this event for you by default.